# Setting ListView heights with 2 ListViews in 1 LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Here is my xml file for my `layout`:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh_scrollview_feat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewFriends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1100dp" >
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewTrending"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1100dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshScrollView>
```

For some reason, the only way to show both `ListViews` is by setting height in actual `dp`'s.  I can't use `wrap_content` or `layout_weights`.

Is this a limitation of using multiple `ListViews`?  Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: A ScrollView with two ListViews embedded? Damn you are totally on the wrong track here... Remove the ScrollView and try `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"` on both ListViews... are you sure that you need two ListViews in one layout?

Comment: What kind of functionality are you trying to achieve. As @WarrenFaith expressed, the UI you're implementing seems a bit buggy.

Comment: @WarrenFaith  The problem with that setup is, 50% of the screen shows one listview, 50% shows the other - at all times.  I want it to be one continuous scroll.  Maybe put the second listview in the footer of the first one?

Comment: You should then just merge both into one. This isn't really a problem...

Comment: @WarrenFaith  Ok, but _how_ do you do this?  Merging?  All I want is the activity to appear to flow.

Comment: _appear to flow_ what ever this means... and yes, like you said below: use one listview and a merge adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I simply scrapped this idea and used a `MergeAdapter` and got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `PullToRefreshScrollView` is some sort of `ScrollView`. You should not use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`; they just do not play well together. Not only must you must set an explicit layout height for the list(s), but the two views will get in each other's way in dealing with touch events.

If you promote the `LinearLayout` to the top of the container hierarchy, you can set the following attributes for each `ListView`:

```
. . .
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
. . .
```

They should then take up the same vertical space.

Comment: The thing is, I need to scroll cause they lists are long.  So how can I achieve that?

Comment: @KickingLettuce - A `ListView` already scrolls. In fact, that's why it doesn't work well inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: yes, if this was about one listview that matters, with two it acts differently.   Doing it with your suggestion merely splits the screen in two and and shows both listviews at any given time. I need the two views to appear continuous, almost like what a header does.  I'm starting to think there is no good way to do this and I need to use one listview and simply MergeAdapter.

Comment: @KickingLettuce - I didn't understand exactly what you were trying to accomplish. A `MergeAdapter` does sound like the best thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but could you set layout_height=0dp and layout_weight=1 to your ListViews and see what happens?

Hope it helps.